# Sending value on dismissal of sheet segue?

Tags: swift, macos, segue, nsviewcontroller, nsstoryboard

I am struggling to find recent documentation and information on the sheet segue, hence my asking. I have a main view controller, which when a button is pressed triggers a sheet segue.

The sheet is then dismissed with another button and I am looking to transfer a value back to the original view controller when the sheet is dismissed.

I have tried using delegates and 'prepare' as if the dismissal is another segue in itself but both proved fruitless.

This may be a simple issue but I am new to the platform, any help much appreciated!

Comment: Two thoughts, one a question for clarification since you really haven't posted anything of detail. (1) What do you mean by "sheet" and "segue"? Most call it view controller and storyboard segue. (I just saw you are talking mass, not UIKit so I may be off. (2) In `UIKit` land where we wish to both "unwind" a segue and pass something back, we (a) create an unwind segue and (b) pass the first view controller *to* the target one. Does that work in macOS?

Comment: Actually, I have a final question - don't answer, it's just my curiosity since I used to do all kinds of "Windows" programming for a few decades... how does a "segue" fit into a windows environment?

Comment: @dfd a sheet: [Sheets in 
Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/sheets/), a sheet segue is a Storyboard Segue with kind "Sheet". Have a try, create a macOS Xcode project.

Comment: Sorry for asking obvious questions (to some) concerning a vague question that has close votes (not mine). I "dabbled" in OS X or macOS apps before and have a couple of iOS apps in the App Store. I've also been programming since 1984 professionally on mainframes, Windows, etc. My question was more geared to glean info from *you* to help you get others to understand what the *specific* issue is. And sure, I was curious how one "segues" in a *single* macOS "window" from one sheet to another. You really need more details... maybe some code?